# Invalid foreach argument

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing, encode

I have two json files labelled sample.json and sample2.json. They are both pulling slightly different data but the format should be similar. When I run my script on sample1.json it works. When I run my script on sample.json it fails saying invalid foreach arguments in line 141 and 169.

code for line 141 is here:

```
 foreach($posts as &$entry){

            $mod = new modifier($entry); //create modifier object
            $result = $mod->getResult(); //gives parsed text back
            $entry['mod-post'] = $result;

            $usr = $entry['user']['screen_name'];   //mod the usr as well while we are at it to give a new usr      
            $usr = '@' . $usr;
            $entry['mod-usr'] = $usr;               

    }
```

and when I read the data in it comes in as

```
$datafile = 'data/sample.json';

//open up datafile created through search
$myfile = fopen($datafile, 'r') or die('Unable to open file!!!');
$d = fread($myfile, filesize($datafile));

//file already formatted as json
$data = array();
$data = json_decode($d, true);
$posts = $data["statuses"]; //make easier to access later

fclose($myfile);//close file
```

Based upon what I've seen, I think the issue is that the second json file isn't been read correctly. That being said, when I upload my file to jsonlint or any the json checker, it gives me a invalid json for BOTH files (or which I have no idea why. I'm pulling the data from twitter so it should be fine).

I've linked the json files if you have the time to take a quick look.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zqwqtbav7ii9if/sample1.json?dl=0

and

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xh94csike6ucqc/sample.json?dl=0

Even if you can just give me a hint as to what the problem might be, and moreover why my program can run on sample1.json but not sample.json it would be helpful.

Comment: Update: I have been checking the json files and JSON Lint gave sample1 a valid response. Seems like json.parser.online.fr/ does not work!!!I will continue to investigate!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem was that sample1.json was in fact valid and sample.json was infact invalid. The problem was **json.parser.online.fr/** was returning an incorrect response by labelling them **BOTH** as **"INVALID".** Not sure exactly why that particular checker was not working (I was using it because you can upload files directly to their site).